# Swift 2 does not recognize "vatiableTableView.reloadData()" anymore?

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, ios9

I'm working now on my first app ever, which is a StopWatch. I have done most of the functions but I faced a problem, which is that Swift 2 does not recognize `vatiableTableView.reloadData()` anymore. This particular part for inserting the laps into the tableview. This code works just fine in IOS8 - Swift but does NOT in IOS9 - Swift 2.

Is there a way around for such a problem?

I made an array variable called:

```
var laps: [String] = ""
```

---

```
@IBAction func PauseResetStopWatch(sender: AnyObject) {

    if addLap == true {

        laps.insert(StopWatchResult, atIndex: 0)
        lapsTableView.reloadData()
```

---

where " laps " is a variable.

--

The error was:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'lapsTableView'

Here is a screen snapshot of that error:

[image: unresolved identifier error]

Comment: if addLap == true  is redundant. use if addLap { ... }

Comment: var laps: [String] = "" won't compile

Comment: I put it that way cause

var addLap = false

Comment: thank you I made the changes

Comment: Anyone can help with this problem ..?

Comment: This code works just fine in IOS8 - Swift but does NOT in IOS9 - Swift 2. This is not true. Your code never worked as it is

Comment: Why you saying that ..?

I'm sorry to tell you that the code works just fine, but I'm facing a problem in reload data.

Comment: I am sorry to inform you that there is no way to assign a string to an array like this

Comment: You alright.

That's why I convert the army to string by doing the following :

var laps: [String] = []

Comment: Please Help Me Out ... Do you need the entire code?

Comment: No, do not post entire code. Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the smallest possible example that reproduces the problem you describe. The problem in your example, is that  you've posted code that wouldn't compile (`var laps: [String] = ""`), you reference one method in your title (`reload()`) but use another in your code snippet (`reloadData()`). If you're having an error, share the precise error message. If it's not working, describe what it's doing and what diagnostics you've performed.

Comment: What is `reload`? Please post code that shows where it is defined and used. What exactly you see when you say "Swift 2 does not recognize..." - is there any specific error message? Also, your title says `vatiableTableView` and your sample code says `lapsTableView`. Are these two different table views?

Comment: Please look at the following images :


https://www.mediafire.com/?z1fooqssxupcd3h
https://www.mediafire.com/?z1fooqssxupcd3h

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'lapsTableView'

Thus, there is nothing wrong with `reloadData`. Instead it's telling you that it cannot find the `lapsTableView` property at all.

You question's title references a different table view name. Perhaps you meant to use that instead of `lapsTableView`. Go back and confirm the name of the property that references the table view, as it would appear that it is not `lapsTableView`.